# Does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}}$ Diverge Or Converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am told it diverge, however surely;

$$\frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}} = \frac{4^n}{4\cdot 4^n} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Is this a term in a sequence? A term in a series? We need much more detail before we can give a proper answer.

Comment: It is the Sum to Infinity

Comment: Think about it this way: you're adding up $\frac{1}{4}$ over and over again. Does this approach a finite value?

Comment: Ah of course. My mistake, so i have 1/4 * infinity basically. So it diverges as it does not converge to a number.

Comment: Exactly right :)

Comment: Just looking at my notes, is this a example of the "Vanishing Test"?

Comment: If by "vanishing test" you mean that a series can only converge if its summand goes to zero, this is true. Note that just because the summand does go to zero does not mean the series will converge though.

Comment: Thank you for your help Cameron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}} =  \frac{1}{4}\neq 0$$
the [general term test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) says that this series is divergent.

Comment: Sorry i am unfamiliar with the "term test" is this the same as the Vanishing test?

Comment: please see the given link.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

$$a_n={4^n\over 4^{n+1}}={4^n\over 4^n\cdot 4}={1\over 4}$$

Do you mean the sequence or the series?

If you are asking $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$, then you have your answer.

If you are asking $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, then again the above shows the $n$th term tends to $1/4$, so the series must diverge.

You have to be careful about whether you are consider the *sequence* $\{a_n\}$ or the *series* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. Huge difference.

Comment: Why? He did not specify seq or series.

Comment: Just flag the troll.

Comment: Don't give an answer without knowing the full problem. You merely posted work OP already had in his/her post when he/she first posed the question.

Comment: You seem to have not bothered to read the main thrust: my last question asking seq or series tells him that how he answers that (combined with his calculation), will determine the answer. But troll on.

Comment: There's no trolling to be had here. Your initial post contained absolutely *nothing* worthy of an answer. You don't post one line of work and then ask what OP means and claim this as an answer. These kinds of things are left as comments. Notice that I did exactly this because what OP meant was unclear. I was waiting to give an answer until OP clarified whether a series or a sequence was meant.

Comment: That's your opinion and you are entitled to it. I disagree. Have a nice day.

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion. This is general community guideline. But since you have edited your post (quite well), I have removed the downvote. I had to edit your post (put a space in it) in order to undo the downvote though.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges, because
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4}$$
and a series can only converge if the sequence that is summed up converges to $0$.